# How do you check a python string to see if it's in HH:MM time format?

Tags: python, regex, time

what is a regex for matching the HH:MM time format in python?
I was using

```
def is_time(self, str):
    reg = re.compile(r'[1-9]|1[0-2]:[0-9]{2}')

    if re.match(reg, str):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I've also tried :

```
reg = re.compile(r'^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$')
```

but i keep getting

> TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

it makes sense that I'm getting that error because I'm checking numbers in strings, but I'm not sure how to fix it. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI the `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use just:

```
if reg.search(strs)
```

or simply:

`return reg.search(strs)`.

Comment: or `return reg.search(str)`

Comment: @AlexW.H.B. don't use `str` as a variable name.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary is that not pythonic?

Comment: `str` is the same as a common function that casts a variable as a string.

Comment: @AlexW.H.B. `str` is a built-in function.

Comment: Python is actually graciously letting you hang yourself, which is so pythonic, if you really think about it :)

Comment: @JasonSperske ha ha ha... How nice of it! I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 7):

You should probably use `datetime.strptime`

```
>>> import datetime

>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('12:34', '%H:%M')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 34)

>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('99:99', '%H:%M')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '99:99' does not match format '%H:%M'
```